# Is this 3D graphics computation question from Photo-SE on topic here?

Tags: discussion, migration, topical

Over at Photo-SE, we have a question from a new user that seems like it would be on-topic here:

[Calculating the new coordinate of a point in the camera field of view after rotating the camera around the z -axis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/114499/calculating-the-new-coordinate-of-a-point-in-the-camera-field-of-view-after-rota)

I just wanted to check with your Meta before I vote to migrate the question over here.

---

**Note**: I also cross-posted this meta-question at [Computer Graphics SE](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294/is-this-3d-graphics-computation-question-from-photo-se-on-topic-here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "a perfect match" for our site, as we don't generally deal with simulating lenses and/or focal lengths, but I don't think it's completely off-topic either. I will not vote to close if it's migrated here.

If folks over ComputerGraphics give you a more enthusiastic answer, maybe you could move it there instead :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Based on the [answer at CGSE](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/295/11837), I'm going to recommend it over there, rather than here. Cheers! =)